# windows - How can i access total "user mode stack trace database(ust)"?

Tags: c++, windows, windbg, gflags

How can i access the total "user mode stack trace database" created by "gflags.exe" like sql DB?
Otherwise, could you tell me some API docs about ust DB?

I truned on the +ust flag using "gflags.exe", So i can get stack trace creating a memory block.

But i want to compile statistics memory allocation group by callstack (like umdh or leakdiag) just for study.
I guess there is some interface for query the ust DB, but i can't find.. 
Is there some way to query to or enumerate the ust DB?

Comment: There is no API. Just use umdh.exe to access UST information inside the running process. It would help if you clarify what your end goal is. If this is finding a memory leaks, just use a guadance at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-umdh-to-find-a-user-mode-memory-leak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UMDH as the API. UMDH uses text files to store its data:

```
umdh -pn:Program.exe -f:before.txt
// do something
umdh -pn:Program.exe -f:after.txt
```

And you can even repeat these steps to get more text files. You then have n text files (that's your "database") that you can parse (you'll have to write the query in some programming language like C# or Python) and analyze.

There are tools out there which already work like this. In my former company we used UMDHGrapher (not publically available) and there is [UmdhViz](https://github.com/Nettention/UmdhViz) or [Umdh Visualize](http://www.dorodnic.com/blog/2014/04/05/dont-fear-the-memory-leak-2/) which all do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at avrfsdk.h  it exposes some interfaces to play with Stack_trace_database

a sample code that shows how to get an allocation stack trace is shown below

compile without optimizations
**(cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /Od foo.cpp /link / release)**

enable pageheap and collect stack trace on the compiled exe
**gflags /i foo.exe +ust +hpa**

run it to get the stacktrace for the single malloc() in allocme()

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <avrfsdk.h>
#include <intrin.h>
#define ALLOCSIZ 0x1337
typedef ULONG(WINAPI * VerifierEnumResource)(HANDLE Process, ULONG  Flags,
    ULONG  ResourceType, AVRF_RESOURCE_ENUMERATE_CALLBACK ResourceCallback,
    PVOID  EnumerationContext
    );
ULONG WINAPI HeapAllocCallback(PAVRF_HEAP_ALLOCATION HeapAllocation, PVOID, PULONG) {
    if (HeapAllocation->UserAllocationSize == ALLOCSIZ) {
        printf("Index=%x\tDepth=%x\n", HeapAllocation->BackTraceInformation->Index,
            HeapAllocation->BackTraceInformation->Depth);
        for (ULONG i = 0; i < HeapAllocation->BackTraceInformation->Depth; i++) {
            printf("%I64x\n", HeapAllocation->BackTraceInformation->ReturnAddresses[i]);
        }
    }return 0;
}
char * allocme() { printf("%p\n", _ReturnAddress()); return (char *)malloc(ALLOCSIZ); }
int main(void) {
    char *foo = allocme();
    if (foo) {
        memcpy(foo, "VerifierEnumerateResource\0", 26);
        HMODULE hMod;
        if ((hMod = LoadLibraryA("verifier.dll")) == NULL) { return 0; }
        VerifierEnumResource VerEnuRes;
        if ((*(FARPROC *)&VerEnuRes = GetProcAddress(hMod, foo)) == NULL) {
            return 0;
        };
        HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
        VerEnuRes(hProcess, 0, AvrfResourceHeapAllocation,
            (AVRF_RESOURCE_ENUMERATE_CALLBACK)HeapAllocCallback, NULL);
    }return getchar();
}
```

result of execution

```
:>ls
dbstk.cpp

:>cl /nologo /Zi /W4 /analyze /Od dbstk.cpp /link /nologo /release
dbstk.cpp

:>gflags /i dbstk.exe +ust +hpa
Current Registry Settings for dbstk.exe executable are: 02001000
    ust - Create user mode stack trace database
    hpa - Enable page heap
:>dbstk.exe
008710CB <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 
Index=0 Depth=b
10c38e89
77105ede
770ca40a
77095ae0
890e7d
8710ae
8710cb <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
871390
76c4ed6c
770a37eb
770a37be
```